# Manage session storage tab wise using AWS Cognito in angular 4

Tags: angular, authentication, amazon-cognito

For user login/authentication I am using

```
import { CognitoUtil, CognitoCallback, LoggedInCallback } from './cognito.service';
```

in authentication service and using session storage. So as soon as user logged-in session storage token is saved. But as soon as user open any other page in new tab session storage gets destroyed and user is asked to log-in again.

How can I make this session-storage work tab wise?